# Can't properly install hardhat using Powershell! Persistent Error HH12: Trying to use a non-local installation of Hardhat, which is not supported

Tags: installation, deployment, global, local, hardhat

Below is a short list of my setup until I stumble upon the HH12 Hardhat Error that I keep getting:

1. mkdir wave (Name of my directory)
2. cd wave
3. npm init -y
4. npm install —save-dev hardhat
5. npx hardhat
6. Choose sample project
   6a. Hardhat project root (Select)
   6b. Add .gitignore
7. Say yes to everything
8. install the remaining dependencies:  npm install --save-dev @nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle ethereum-waffle chai @nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers ethers
9. npx hardhat accounts (to see all the different accounts)...

...And then it fails here!  An HH12 Hardhat Error Message: "Hardhat is not installed or installed globally.  You tried to run Hardhat from a global installation or not installing it at all. This is not supported.  Please install Hardhat locally using npm or Yarn, and try again." (https://hardhat.org/errors/) [BTW, these 2 lines are the ONLY docs on this error on Hardhat!].

Any suggestions?

I have tried the following possible 'fixes' to sidestep this error but to no avail:

- Updating most current version of node
- Restarting my PC (About 17 X now as of this writing)
- Using GitBash (Instead of Powershell)
- Asking mods in Hardhat Discord (None) and other Discords
- Opening the Hardhat docs (And the Tutorials!!) for answers... None!
- StackExchange - There's literally only 1 other person who ALSO had this problem here!  But the answers here are not the solution. (Have DMd that person but no reply as of yet).

So can anyone out there help?

Answer (score 1):

I believe I finally figured out the solution (at least what worked for me):

1. I dropped back 2 directory levels from where I was for my root project and started again there.
2. I updated my Node version to 16.